# WSO2AM Analytics - duplicate key value in DB logs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

having WSO2AM 2.1.0 with analytics (wso2am-analytics-2.1.0) with PostgreSQL the database team complains about too many database errors in the analytics database (too many is approx 1.5GB / day and we have almost no traffic)

Database logs:

```
<PGSCYANAES-scyanaes-2017-10-10 09:35:22 CEST>ERROR:  duplicate key value 
violates unique constraint "anx___7lv6kvss__pkey"
<PGSCYANAES-scyanaes-2017-10-10 09:35:22 CEST>DETAIL:  Key 
(record_id)=(64d8b03f-9e60-3d2e-837e-3df5103620e7) already exists.
<PGSCYANAES-scyanaes-2017-10-10 09:35:22 CEST>STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO 
ANX___7Lv6kvss_ (partition_key, timestamp, data, record_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
<PGSCYANAES-scyanaes-2017-10-10 09:35:22 CEST>ERROR:  duplicate key value 
violates unique constraint "anx___7lv6kvss__pkey"
```

I've seen these entries in the wso2carbon.log before, but after recreating the databases and resintling the analytics server, the wso2carbon.log looks clean. However - the database team keeps claiming these errors are still occuring (a lot)

Edit:

we found out there's a configutation file with SQL statements `rdbms-config.xml` 
 and there are several statements causing the errors in the db logs:

```
<recordInsertQuery>INSERT INTO {{TABLE_NAME}} (partition_key, timestamp, data, record_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) </recordInsertQuery>
```

This statement seems to cause the most of the error logs.

I've changed the statement to:

```
INSERT INTO {{TABLE_NAME}} (partition_key, timestamp, data, record_id) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) 
ON CONFLICT (record_id) 
DO UPDATE SET partition_key=EXCLUDED.partition_key, timestamp=EXCLUDED.timestamp, data=EXCLUDED.data
```

Until now it looks all working, but I may be not aware of all consequences and side-effects of this update. Is there any problem that can arise using the new upsert statement?

Thank you in advance for any hint / help